transform canvas command stops working when text is too small
This is a follow up from a previous question, where I received a useful answer.
The solution worked for me initially, but now it seems to stop working when the text size is too small?
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

% Imported Packages
\usepackage{amsmath, comment}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Circle Packing}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,transform canvas={scale=2}]
        \draw[ultra thin] (0.0000000000in, 0.0000000000in) circle (3.0000000000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (0.0000000000in, 1.2500000000in) circle (1.7500000000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (-0.4941176471in, -1.6941176471in) circle (1.2352941176in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (1.6800000000in, -0.9900000000in) circle (1.0500000000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (0.4800000000in, -0.6400000000in) circle (0.2000000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (0.5558823529in, -0.9066176471in) circle (0.0772058824in);
        \draw[thin, red] (0.6863813230in, -0.4482490272in) circle (0.0817120623in);
        \draw[thin, red] (0.2032258065in, -0.5733870968in) circle (0.0846774194in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (1.0500000000in, -2.3375000000in) circle (0.4375000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (0.8542372881in, -1.8169491525in) circle (0.1186440678in);
        \draw[thin, red] (1.6800000000in, -2.2400000000in) circle (0.2000000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (0.5250000000in, -2.7312500000in) circle (0.2187500000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (2.2909090909in, 0.5818181818in) circle (0.6363636364in);
        \draw[thin, red] (1.5941605839in, 0.2102189781in) circle (0.1532846715in);
        \draw[thin, red] (2.7300000000in, -0.2025000000in) circle (0.2625000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (2.1000000000in, 1.5750000000in) circle (0.3750000000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (-2.1000000000in, -0.3250000000in) circle (0.8750000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (-1.0407079646in, -0.3823008850in) circle (0.1858407080in);
        \draw[thin, red] (-2.1000000000in, -1.5750000000in) circle (0.3750000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (-2.2536585366in, 1.0536585366in) circle (0.5121951220in);
        \node[align=center] at (0in, 1.25in) {\fontsize{.3475in}{0in}\selectfont 12};
        \node[align=center] at (-0.4941176471in, -1.6941176471in) {\fontsize{.3075in}{0in}\selectfont 17};
        \node[align=center] at (1.68in, -0.99in) {\fontsize{.2625in}{0in}\selectfont 20};
        \node[align=center] at (0.48in, -0.64in) {\fontsize{0.04in}{0in}\selectfont 105};
        \node[align=center] at (0.5558823529in, -0.9066176471in) {\fontsize{0.0154in}{0in}\selectfont 272};
        \node[align=center] at (0.6863813230in, -0.4482490272in) {\fontsize{0.01635in}{0in}\selectfont 257};
        \node[align=center] at (0.2032258065in, -0.5733870968in) {\fontsize{0.016935in}{0in}\selectfont 248};
        \node[align=center] at (1.05in, -2.3375in) {\fontsize{0.109375in}{0in}\selectfont 48};
        \node[align=center] at (0.8542372881in, -1.8169491525in) {\fontsize{0.023728in}{0in}\selectfont 177};
        \node[align=center] at (1.68in, -2.24in) {\fontsize{0.04in}{0in}\selectfont 105};
        \node[align=center] at (0.525in, -2.73125in) {\fontsize{0.0546875in}{0in}\selectfont 96};
        \node[align=center] at (2.2909090909in, 0.5818181818in) {\fontsize{0.159075in}{0in}\selectfont 33};
        \node[align=center] at (1.5941605839in, 0.2102189781in) {\fontsize{0.03065in}{0in}\selectfont 137};
        \node[align=center] at (2.7300000000in, -0.2025000000in) {\fontsize{0.065625in}{0in}\selectfont 80};
        \node[align=center] at (2.1000000000in, 1.5750000000in) {\fontsize{0.09375in}{0in}\selectfont 56};
        \node[align=center] at (-2.1000000000in, -0.3250000000in) {\fontsize{0.21875in}{0in}\selectfont 24};
        \node[align=center] at (-1.0407079646in, -0.3823008850in) {\fontsize{0.03715in}{0in}\selectfont 113};
        \node[align=center] at (-2.1000000000in, -1.5750000000in) {\fontsize{0.09375in}{0in}\selectfont 56};
        \node[align=center] at (-2.2536585366in, 1.0536585366in) {\fontsize{0.128in}{0in}\selectfont 41};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


You can see the small text in the middle is not scaled correct. Am I using transform canvas incorrectly?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Can't reproduce the problem. Do you use a scaleable font like in my answer?

it makes no sense to enter the lengths to spurious accuracy such as 0.5558823529in  that is equal to 0.5559in  TeX uses fixed point arithmetic with at most 5dp pt accuracy

@DavidCarlisle Ups! What a badly placed typo.

I edited it so my code is compliable, sorry about that.

If you want to use arbitrary font sizes, you need a scaleable font, e.g. by loading the lmodern package:
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

% Imported Packages
\usepackage{
%amsmath, 
comment}
%\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Circle Packing}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,transform canvas={scale=2}]
        \draw[ultra thin] (0.0000000000in, 0.0000000000in) circle (3.0000000000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (0.0000000000in, 1.2500000000in) circle (1.7500000000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (-0.4941176471in, -1.6941176471in) circle (1.2352941176in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (1.6800000000in, -0.9900000000in) circle (1.0500000000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (0.4800000000in, -0.6400000000in) circle (0.2000000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (0.5558823529in, -0.9066176471in) circle (0.0772058824in);
        \draw[thin, red] (0.6863813230in, -0.4482490272in) circle (0.0817120623in);
        \draw[thin, red] (0.2032258065in, -0.5733870968in) circle (0.0846774194in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (1.0500000000in, -2.3375000000in) circle (0.4375000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (0.8542372881in, -1.8169491525in) circle (0.1186440678in);
        \draw[thin, red] (1.6800000000in, -2.2400000000in) circle (0.2000000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (0.5250000000in, -2.7312500000in) circle (0.2187500000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (2.2909090909in, 0.5818181818in) circle (0.6363636364in);
        \draw[thin, red] (1.5941605839in, 0.2102189781in) circle (0.1532846715in);
        \draw[thin, red] (2.7300000000in, -0.2025000000in) circle (0.2625000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (2.1000000000in, 1.5750000000in) circle (0.3750000000in);
        \draw[ultra thin] (-2.1000000000in, -0.3250000000in) circle (0.8750000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (-1.0407079646in, -0.3823008850in) circle (0.1858407080in);
        \draw[thin, red] (-2.1000000000in, -1.5750000000in) circle (0.3750000000in);
        \draw[thin, red] (-2.2536585366in, 1.0536585366in) circle (0.5121951220in);
        \node[align=center] at (0in, 1.25in) {\fontsize{.3475in}{0in}\selectfont 12};
        \node[align=center] at (-0.4941176471in, -1.6941176471in) {\fontsize{.3075in}{0in}\selectfont 17};
        \node[align=center] at (1.68in, -0.99in) {\fontsize{.2625in}{0in}\selectfont 20};
        \node[align=center] at (0.48in, -0.64in) {\fontsize{0.04in}{0in}\selectfont 105};
        \node[align=center] at (0.5558823529in, -0.9066176471in) {\fontsize{0.0154in}{0in}\selectfont 272};
        \node[align=center] at (0.6863813230in, -0.4482490272in) {\fontsize{0.01635in}{0in}\selectfont 257};
        \node[align=center] at (0.2032258065in, -0.5733870968in) {\fontsize{0.016935in}{0in}\selectfont 248};
        \node[align=center] at (1.05in, -2.3375in) {\fontsize{0.109375in}{0in}\selectfont 48};
        \node[align=center] at (0.8542372881in, -1.8169491525in) {\fontsize{0.023728in}{0in}\selectfont 177};
        \node[align=center] at (1.68in, -2.24in) {\fontsize{0.04in}{0in}\selectfont 105};
        \node[align=center] at (0.525in, -2.73125in) {\fontsize{0.0546875in}{0in}\selectfont 96};
        \node[align=center] at (2.2909090909in, 0.5818181818in) {\fontsize{0.159075in}{0in}\selectfont 33};
        \node[align=center] at (1.5941605839in, 0.2102189781in) {\fontsize{0.03065in}{0in}\selectfont 137};
        \node[align=center] at (2.7300000000in, -0.2025000000in) {\fontsize{0.065625in}{0in}\selectfont 80};
        \node[align=center] at (2.1000000000in, 1.5750000000in) {\fontsize{0.09375in}{0in}\selectfont 56};
        \node[align=center] at (-2.1000000000in, -0.3250000000in) {\fontsize{0.21875in}{0in}\selectfont 24};
        \node[align=center] at (-1.0407079646in, -0.3823008850in) {\fontsize{0.03715in}{0in}\selectfont 113};
        \node[align=center] at (-2.1000000000in, -1.5750000000in) {\fontsize{0.09375in}{0in}\selectfont 56};
        \node[align=center] at (-2.2536585366in, 1.0536585366in) {\fontsize{0.128in}{0in}\selectfont 41};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Thanks Sam! This stuff is so darn finicky. It's amazing to be able to ask a pro and get an answer in 15mins!

@ClydeKertzer You see why it is so essential to always include a compilable example in your questions? People need to be able to see if you are missing a package.

Yes, it's quite useful. I'll be sure to have the appropriate format in future questions.

@ClydeKertzer also it shows not to ignore warnings. Latex will have warned the font was not available at the requested size

Ah yeah thanks for pointing that out!
